# Video cat ear filter too wiggly

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, video-processing

I am making a video filter that adds cat ears to you like a Snapchat lenses. I am using opencv4 and Dlib. Dlib takes care of detecting the face. The problem is because of detection coordinates changes a little every frame the filter is too wiggly.

I tried to change the place of ears every 2-3 frames but not much changed.

```
while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()
    ear_mask.fill(0)
    gray_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = detector(frame)

    for face in faces:
        ear_width, ear_height, top_left, degree = generateNewEar(frame)
        frame = generateImage(frame, ear_width,
                              ear_height, top_left, degree)
    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
```

How do people usually handle this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"The problem is, because of detection, the coordinates changes a little bit every frame so the filter is too wiggly."*

I don't use Python or OpenCV so I can't show you an example code. Some advice you can try.

**(1)** Camera noise could be affecting the detection. Try a soft blur on the input to smooth the pixels. Test different blur levels.

**(2)** Try updating ear positions once every second, then fine tune to *X* times per sec.

**(3)** Compare ear position of current frame vs previous frame. If distance too small (1 or 2 pixels) then ignore and use old position.